# How to calculate sheath area

Tags: low-earth-orbit, plasma

Suppose we have a cubesat in LEO, if the metallic surface of the satellite is at a positive potential it will attract electrons from the ionosphere plasma, the current collected will be I = J * A, with J the current density of the plasma and A The sheath area, at higher voltages the area will be larger, but how can I calculate this area given a certain potential?

Comment: For a very rough number, I wonder if it is possible to use the [Child Langmuir law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_sheath#The_Child%E2%80%93Langmuir_law) to estimate the sheath distance then use it as a radius of a sphere and calculate its area? There's also [Analytical and exact solutions of the spherical and cylindrical diodes of Langmuir–Blodgett law](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5003942) (paywalled) and [Novel Scaling Laws for the Langmuir-Blodgett Solutions in Cylindrical and Spherical Diodes](https://www.egr.msu.edu/~pz/prl2013.pdf)

Comment: (also [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243458155_Novel_Scaling_Laws_for_the_Langmuir-Blodgett_Solutions_in_Cylindrical_and_Spherical_Diodes)) and [Theory of Spherical and Cylindrical Langmuir Probes in a Collisionless, Maxwellian Plasma at Rest](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/634596.pdf)

Comment: Here's NASA's handbook on this and related topics   https://standards.nasa.gov/file/7846/download?token=Sn8LMxdg

Comment: thanks so much, i start a bounty for more information

Comment: Hopefully someone can use those references and write up a nice answer!